# Concatenar variable a html en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hola buenos días tengo un problema a la hora que le quiero pasar como parámetro mi variable a la función. Les anexo mi código.

> Código

```js
var fruta = "hola";

var html = '';
                          html += "<div class='card direct-chat direct-chat-primary'>"+
                            "<div class='card-header'>"+
                              "<h3 class='card-title'>Comentarios</h3>"+
                            "</div>"+
                            "<div class='card-body'>"+
                              "<div class='direct-chat-messages'>"+

                                comentarios+

                              "</div>"+
                            "</div>"+

                            "<div class='card-footer'>"+
                              "<form>"+
                                "<div class='input-group'>"+
                                  "<input type='text' id='form-input-comentario' name='message' placeholder='Comentario ...' class='form-control'>"+
                                  "<span class='input-group-append'>"+
                                    "<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='set_comentario_ajax("+frutas+");'>Enviar</button>"+
                                  "</span>"+
                                "</div>"+
                              "</form>"+
                            "</div>"+
                          "</div>"+

                          "<div class='custom-file'>"+
                            "<input type='file' class='custom-file-input' id='customFile'>"+
                            "<label class='custom-file-label' for='customFile'>Seleccione</label>"+
                          "</div>";
                          $('#form-ticket-comentarios').html(html);
```

> Función que quiero llamar

```js
function set_comentario_ajax(data){
  var porId = document.getElementById("form-input-comentario").value;
  alert(porId);
  console.log(data);
}
```

> Error

***ReferenceError: hola is not defined Tickets:1:1***

Yo supongo que estoy concatenándole mal mi variable “frutas” como parámetro a la función

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evita concatenar contenido, siempre suele ser origen de errores como el que tienes ahora, en su lugar, usa [plantillas de texto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings), encerrando el contenido entre acentos graves (*backticks* en inglés) `` ` `` y, cada que necesites incluir una variable solo necesitas `${nombre_de_variable}`

```js
var fruta = 'hola';
var comentarios = '<p>Comentario 1</p><p>Comentario 2</p><p>Comentario 3</p>';

var html = "";
                          html += `<div class="card direct-chat direct-chat-primary">
                            <div class="card-header">
                              <h3 class="card-title">Comentarios</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                              <div class="direct-chat-messages">

                                ${comentarios}

                              </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="card-footer">
                              <form>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                  <input type="text" id="form-input-comentario" name="message" placeholder="Comentario ..." class="form-control">
                                  <span class="input-group-append">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="set_comentario_ajax('${fruta}');">Enviar</button>
                                  </span>
                                </div>
                              </form>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="custom-file">
                            <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
                            <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Seleccione</label>
                          </div>`;
                          $("#form-ticket-comentarios").html(html);

function set_comentario_ajax(valor) {
    console.log(valor);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form-ticket-comentarios"></div>
```

Comment: me sigue marcando aun el mismmo error ReferenceError: fruta is not defined

Comment: Al inicio de tu pregunta tienes `var fruta = "hola";`, lo que me hace pensar que no pusiste aquí tu código real y así va a ser difícil poder ayudarte. Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código donde obtienes el valor de `fruta`.

Comment: si es mi código real y solo aplique los cambios que me dijiste

Comment: Si lo hiciste tal cual no debería dar error. ¿Ejecutaste el _fragmento de código_? Ahí no se ven errores. Entonces habría que ver cómo y dónde pusiste todo, tal vez está en diferente contexto (scope).

Comment: de echo si le quito el parámetro a la función y se lo quito también al onclick y le pongo un alert si corre la funcion

Comment: Probablemente es en la función donde no puedes acceder a la variable. Actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: Ya quedo, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estas mandando una variable que en el html no existe, asi que deberías agregar unas comillas,

Para que se especifique desde JavaScript como string

También te recomiendo utilizar ${} dentro de donde quieras insertar una variable,
debe ir dentro de estas comillas (``)

```
  `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="set_comentario_ajax('${fruta}')">Enviar</button>`
```

No es necesario el uso de ";" en onclick

Comment: muchas gracias ya quedo

Comment: Espero haberte ayudado

Comment: me ayudaste bastante. Saludos y buen día

Answer (score 0):

Intenta agregar el parámetro con comillas sencillas:

```
    html += "<div class='card direct-chat direct-chat-primary'>"+
  "<div class='card-header'>"+
    "<h3 class='card-title'>Comentarios</h3>"+
  "</div>"+
  "<div class='card-body'>"+
    "<div class='direct-chat-messages'>"+

      comentarios+

    "</div>"+
  "</div>"+

  "<div class='card-footer'>"+
    "<form>"+
      "<div class='input-group'>"+
        "<input type='text' id='form-input-comentario' name='message' placeholder='Comentario ...' class='form-control'>"+
        "<span class='input-group-append'>"+
          "<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='set_comentario_ajax(\'"+frutas+"\');'>Enviar</button>"+
        "</span>"+
      "</div>"+
    "</form>"+
  "</div>"+
"</div>"+

"<div class='custom-file'>"+
  "<input type='file' class='custom-file-input' id='customFile'>"+
  "<label class='custom-file-label' for='customFile'>Seleccione</label>"+
"</div>";
```

Comment: me manda el siguiente error SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'

Comment: He editado la respuesta, agregando el contenido completo de la variable html para que puedas comparar.

Comment: aun me sigue marcando SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'